# Is there any missing code to get the output?

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, random, global

I'm developing a python's mini project using random module. I also added tkinter as GUI.

So, the script is The task is to create a script that generates a random number between a fixed range, and if the
user guesses the number right in three chances, then user wins otherwise user lose.
This game user can play as many numbers of times and whenever user wins a score is to be given
to the user.

```
global ranNum global chance usr_ip = var.get() if chance > 0:
    if usr_ip == ranNum:
       msg = f'CONRATULATIONS!.'
    elif usr_ip > ranNum: chance -= 1
       msg = f'{usr_ip} too high. You have {chance} attempt left.' elif usr_ip < ranNum:
           chance -= 1
       msg = f'{usr_ip} too small. You have {chance} attempt left.' else:
          msg = 'Something went wrong!'
    else:
          msg = f'BETTER LUCK NEXT TIME!!
```

I tried this code but could not get the output.

Comment: Update your code, so people can just copy and run it for testing.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].  Currently it is not known what the types of `var`, `chance` and `ranNum` are.

Comment: you need to  add  `print(msg)` to print the message.